# How to get the path to a non-current directory without stepping in it?

Tags: c, shell, path

I have to list all c files in a given directory and in its subdirectories.
I would like to do this in a single command if it's possible, because I have to solve this problem in c with more processes (using popen and pclose) and I think it would be easier, but it's not necessary.

So my program gets a directory name, and I have to list all c files in it, that's why i'd like to get the path to it without actually going to that directory and using pwd.

I am able to list all c files in a directory with

```
 ls $path | find -type f -name '*c' | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev
```

but how cat I get the path?

for example the 'd' directory is in:

a/b/c/d

and currently I am in:

a/b/f/g and i'd like the path to d, such as: a/b/c/d

Comment: Could you please do add some samples of output in your post and let us know to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, you need to have some way of detailing which directory you need.  For example, there are nearly 2000 directories on the laptop I am using, if I wanted to list a directory I wasn't in that would be 2000-1 directories as output.  I don't think that is what you want, so let me give you some alternatives.

1. Use a relative path

Doing this you would do something like a `ls ../../c/d` which would work, provided you run the command from the "right" directory.

2. Use an absolute path

Doing this you would do something like a  `ls /some/path/to/a/b/c/d` which would work, even if you ran the command in a different directory.

3. Find some number of directories from a relative path.

This would do something like `find ../../c -type d` which would print out all the directories under `../../c`.   This command would output a list of directories.

4. Find some number of directories from an absolute path.

This would do something like `find /some/path/to/a/b/c -type d` which would print out all the directories under `/some/path/to/a/b/c`.  This command would output a list of directories.

All other techniques of finding directories is a variant on the two main approaches (absolute and relative paths) above, and the output would be at a single depth or multiple depths, depending on if you use `ls` or `find`